# I have taken down notes for the book that I read or I took down notes for books that I have read

Tags: word-usage

which one is correct. I have been confused by past tense and present perfect.

Comment: "I have taken notes" suggests that the task was recently finished. If you are talking about work done further back in the past, it would be better to say "I took notes on books that I had read".

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi CCC, it's important to look up a grammar book or a web page on tenses before you ask this kind of question here, as it will often provide the solution. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)